# Volume keys not working

Tags: volume-control

on a random basis, volume keys do not work, mute, up and down.
I must relog in order to make them work again.
Ubuntu 15.04.

What is the issue ?

Comment: Glad to see I am not the only one! This affects my brightness buttons as well.